# How to render on another computer using Adobe Media Encoder CC

Tags: video, premiere

I use a macbook air (1,7Ghz i7, 8gb RAM) to edit my Premiere projects. Rendering blows CPU to the max. I also have a MacMini fileserver (2,6Ghz i5, 8gb RAM) which could be used for rendering jobs.

Is it possible to allocate rendering jobs from Premiere Pro CC on my Macbook Air to the MacMini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not from one computer to another, you'd have to copy the project files onto a server, NAS device, or external HDD and then load it on the MacMini. You cannot from your Air directly say hey PP on the MacMini let's do this unfortunately.

Now, one option would be network rendering. The thing about it is, both computers are required to have exactly the same project files which means it has to be hosted on a server or some sort of NAS device (costly, and won't benefit your setup that much), some frames get rendered on one, while frames get rendered on the other (both computers will be actively involved, so most likely you couldn't work on other projects).

PP does not support network rendering, so the file PP CC file would have to be imported to After Effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) now I know what to do and what not to do.